# Transfer page from internal to external

Tags: seo, transfer, affiliate

Currently I have a website with a list of audio products (essentially a search engine for audio deals). http://www.soundplaza.co.uk

Once you go to the details page, you can then press the 'view deal' button to go to providers site e.g. = http://www.soundplaza.co.uk/all-deals/113/bookshelf-speakers/acoustic-energy-1

This jump between two sites is a bit harsh and I would like to show a transition page, to simply ease them into another site and not scare them off.

Within this tradition page I will have a simple loading gif and some graphics showing that your transferring.

**QUESTION:**

What is the best way to send the details (link, product name etc) to this transfer page, to then wait 5 seconds, to then move on to the desired link... this can in **NO WAY** damage my SEO, if anything `rel="nofollow"` would be great if possible.

I have seen that you can submit form to the transition page, then you can use  php sleep and then php header to transfer... however I am not sure if php header will transfer SEO value to the provider?

Answer (score 1):

Any redirect will work fine. Search engines follow HTTP, JavaScript, and meta redirects without issue. Use whichever method is best for your visitors.

Comment: ok great thanks... so it wont transfer my seo value over to the providers side if i use the php method then? Is there any way of attaching rel="nofollow" or would that not be necessary?